# UILabel can't become first responder and show inputView in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I tried to create a subclass of UILabel called `EditableLabel` and implemented `canBecomeFirstResponder`, `isUserInteractionEnabled`, both of those two methods return `YES`, in the meantime, I over-write `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` and make them writable.

My problem is that when I tap on the label, the inputView can't be shown on the screen. Anybody know how to implement the subclass of UILabel view and let the inputView shown?

Thank you very much.

Comment: From Appe's doc: The UILabel class implements a read-only text view.

Comment: @user523234 Yes, the original UILabel is read-only, but don't forget, UILabel also inherit from UIResponder. So if you over-write those methods I mentioned above, it can show the inputView, also can become first responder. I actually figured out why my code didn't work. I will post update later. Thanks

Comment: Basic code to implement custom `inputView` (`UIDatePicker` in this case but nevertheless...) [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23297991/653513)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `UITextField` and set its `borderStyle` to `UITextBorderStyleNone`?

Comment: Because I don't want to show the cursor to the user. InputView will be UIPickerView