# Trigger PickerView from UILabel to have it Modally Appear From the Bottom the Screen and not Hide/Unhide It

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have label with a gesture recognizer inside a collectionView cell. When the user touches the label I want a pickerView to appear similar to how it would appear when a pickerView is attached to a textField.

I tried `myLabel.inputView = pickerView`

I got this error below.

> Cannot assign to property: 'inputView' is a get-only property

I came across some threads where people were hiding and unhiding the pickerView instead of it popping up and lowering like a it does from a textField but no one explained why they hid/unhid it.

**How can I trigger a PickerView from a UILabel?**

It should be noted that I don't want to hide/unhide it like the other answers that I read.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(triggerPickerView))
        myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }

    @objc func triggerPickerView() {
       print("triggerPickerView")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't set an `inputView` on a `UILabel`… use a `UITextField`

Comment: Hey thanks. Why isn’t possible? I guess whatever the reason that’s why everyone seems to hide/unhide it when using a textfield

Comment: It's not possible because `inputView` is a get only property on `UIResponder` (and therefore `UILabel`).

Comment: thanks for the help. You actually gave me an idea. I can still keep my label and put a clear textField over it and use that to trigger it. FYI I need the label because of the text positioning otherwise I would've used a textField. Enjoy your day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show UIPickerView on label click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319153/show-uipickerview-on-label-click)

Comment: @RakeshaShastri that’s one of the posts I read. It doesn’t explain why a uilabel can’t trigger it like a text field, it just says to hide and a show the picker view. I wanted it to appear like a textfield triggers it.

Comment: Just use `UITextField` or `UITextView` instead of UILabel and set an `inputView` to it.

Comment: @wzbozon thanks for the advice. That's exactly what I did. I was typing my answer as you were leaving your comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

In the comments @AshlyMills said the reason I can't trigger the picker view from a UILabel is because: "*It's not possible because inputView is a get only property on UIResponder*"

My workaround was to a use a UITextField and just make it clear. I added the pickerView as an `inputView` to the textFiled. I laid it directly over the label and by pressing it the pickerView appears modally from the bottom and the label is still visible. I removed the gesture recognizer because it wasn't necessary.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return label
    }()

    let clearTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        return textField
     }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        addSubview(clearTextField)

        clearTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
        clearTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        clearTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        clearTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        clearTextField.inputView = pickerView
    }
}
```

Comment: looking to the question I would suggest you go through the following link -http://stephengroom.co.uk/uikit/showing-ios-keyboard-without-text-input/  here using UIControl you can override inputview functionality, hope it helps.

Comment: @ShivamGaur I’ll look through it in a few. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, property: 'inputView' is a get-only on UILabelView.

if you insist to clicked on a label to have your pickerView, in storyboard you need a fixed UIPickerView inside a view and animate the view (instead of hiding/unhiding) when the label is clicked.

Comment: I read other answers that said to do that but none of them explained why. @AshlyMills explained it. I found a suitable workaround. I posted the answer earlier. Thanks